# Managing multiple Async tasks in android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

Hey everyone so I am just starting a part two for online training app and trying to adapt my async task to get movie reviews from the movie db. Having a totally different async task just for that seems like there should be a better way. Here is the current async task implementation that only gets the movie data.

The question is how do I add another async task to this in order to retrive the movie reviews as well from this url /movie/{id}/videos.

```
public FetchMovieData(Context context, GridView grid, boolean sortType, ITaskCompleteListener listener) {
    mContext = context;
    this.mMoviesGrid = grid;
    this.mSortByMostPopular = sortType;
    this.mTaskCompleteListener = listener;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
    // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url;
        if(mSortByMostPopular)
            url = new URL(mContext.getString(R.string.picasso_url_popular_movies));
        else
            url = new URL(mContext.getString(R.string.picasso_url_highest_rated));

        // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Read the input stream into a String
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        if (inputStream == null) {
            // Nothing to do.
            mMovieJsonStr = null;
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
            // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
            // buffer for debugging.
            buffer.append(line + "\n");
        }

        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
            // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
            mMovieJsonStr = null;
        }
        mMovieJsonStr = buffer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
        // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
        // to parse it.
        mMovieJsonStr = null;
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    if(mMovieJsonStr != null)
        Constants.mMovies = MovieDataParser.getMovieData(mMovieJsonStr);

    mTaskCompleteListener.onTaskCompleted(); //Task completed alert UI that we have our data
}
```

So some one had suggested using Retrofit instead of having multiple async tasks. This seems like a good idea but I am having a lot of trouble understanding how it is supposed to work. Currently I have a WebService class an interface and am trying to use it to retrieve both movies and am going to add reviews then trailers. The issue is if I set the base url as "http://api.themoviedb.org" I get url must start with "/" in logcat.

Current code:

```
public class WebService {
  public List<Movie> getMovies() {

    RestAdapter retrofit = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://api.themoviedb.org")
            .build();

    MovieDBService service = retrofit.create(MovieDBService.class);

    return service.listMovies("movies");
   }
 }

public interface MovieDBService {
                     @GET("/3/discover/{switchterm}sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=d273a1a1fb9390dab9  7ac0032b12366a")

  List listMovies(@Path("switchterm") String switchterm);
}

//In code getting movies
WebService service = new WebService();
List movies = service.getMovies();
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Add url in List and for each url execute the asynctask. Make sure your asynctask SERIAL if your List is big

Comment: I am guessing in your MoviesActivity, you show a list of Movies. When the user clicks on a Movie, you have to show the movie reviews in MovieReviewsActivity. So in the OnItemClickListener of your ListView, you can launch your MovieReviewsAsyncTask in order to Fetch the movie reviews.

Comment: Yeah I am doing the second part for the udacity movies app. Android NanoDeveloper Degree :). Ok I will try this out thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up with was this using the the Retrofit library for the web service. Thanks for the help everyone and let me know your thoughts.

```
public Context mContext;
private MovieJSON mMovieData;
private ReviewJSON mMovieReviews;
private VideoJSON mMovieVideos;
public boolean mSortByMostPopular;
ITaskCompleteListener mTaskCompleteListener;

public FetchMovieData(Context context, boolean sortType, ITaskCompleteListener listener) {
    mContext = context;
    this.mSortByMostPopular = sortType;
    this.mTaskCompleteListener = listener;
}

public void getMovies() {
    new FetchMovies().execute();
}

public void getReviews() {
    new FetchReviews().execute();
}

public void getVideos() {
    new FetchTrailers().execute();
}

private class FetchMovies extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void > {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        WebService service = new WebService();
        //TODO Re-Implement sorting
        mMovieData = service.getMovies();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if(mMovieData != null)
            Constants.mMovies = MovieDataParser.getMovieData(mMovieData);

        mTaskCompleteListener.onTaskCompleted(); //Task completed alert UI that we have our data
    }
}

private class FetchReviews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void > {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        WebService service = new WebService();
        mMovieReviews = service.getReviews();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if(mMovieReviews != null)
            Constants.mReviews = MovieDataParser.getReviewData(mMovieReviews);

        mTaskCompleteListener.onTaskCompleted(); //Task completed alert UI that we have our data
    }
}

private class FetchTrailers extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void > {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        WebService service = new WebService();
        mMovieVideos = service.getVideos();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if(mMovieVideos != null)
            Constants.mTrailers = MovieDataParser.getVideoData(mMovieVideos);

        mTaskCompleteListener.onTaskCompleted(); //Task completed alert UI that we have our data
    }
}
```

//web service

public class WebService {

```
RestAdapter mRetrofit;

MovieDBService mService;

public WebService() {
    mRetrofit = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://api.themoviedb.org")
            .build();
    mService = mRetrofit.create(MovieDBService.class);
}

public MovieJSON getMovies() {
    return mService.listMovies("");
}

public ReviewJSON getReviews() {
    return mService.listReviews("76341");
}

public VideoJSON getVideos() {
    return mService.listVideos("76341");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a lots of possibilities for doing this.You can follow this approach: add a second call to another AsyncTask when the first is finish, and pass to it a list of strings with the video ids:

```
public class FetchMovieData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected Boolean doInBackground() {
       try {
           String movieJSONString = getJSONMovies();
           String[] ids = parseIdsFromJSON(movieJSONString);
           if(ids.lenth != 0) {
               FetchMovieReviews moviesReviewsAsyncTask = new FetchMovieReviews();
               moviesReviewsAsyncTask.execute(ids);
           } else {
               return false;
           }

           return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
           return false;
        }
    }

    protected String getJSONMovies() {
       //with the code you post, return the json string
    }

    protected String[] parseIdsFromJSON(String JSON) {
        //parse the json and get the ids and return
        //return {"1","2","3"}
    }
}

public class FetchMovieReviews extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(String[]... params) {
       for(String id : params[0]) {
           //call the web service and pass the id
       }

       return null;
    }
}
```

You can put all the functionality for manage the calls to the web services in a MoviesRESTCalls class, and for manage the json in a MoviesJSONParser class or something like that, and the code is going to be much more clear.

Comment: hmmm ok i get the idea but how can you guarantee that the first doInBackground() will complete before the movie review doInBackground(). Also could this be put into one class instead of two FetchMovieData classes ?

Comment: Sorry the second AsyncTask is another class "FetchMovieReviews" (an edit error). You can manage with a boolean value, checking if the ids length is distinct to zero (the first web service call return nothing or other error in the json parsing) then you can process the call to the other web services for fetch the reviews. Also if there is another error with the Http connection, throw an exception and don't process the second doInBackground. Answer edited!